What could be the least energy-resource-intensive method of producing heavier elements from lighter ones?
(almost) Cold method. Available light elements are irradiated with neutrons, they capture them, move up the figure (from this) to the blue zone of β-decay, from where they move diagonally to the stable black line, maintaining the number of nucleons, which is greater than the original. In the absence of heavy elements, the most resource-accessible source of neutrons could be the D+D fusion reaction, which seems feasible at a sufficient level of technical development. This also means energy release of approximately $~10^{15,5}$ J per 1 kg of mass change from light to heavy isotope. This limits the feasibility of such transformation is the cost of extraction and delivery being more than $~10^{15}$ J/kg. Although this is not energy consumption, it indicates the scale of the installation and its low productivity. Such an installation will allow determining the amount of necessary isotopes.

Hot method. Available light elements are mixed with deuterium in a sufficiently large size so that it is possible to initiate a thermonuclear explosion with relatively low energy. As a result, the reactions of nuclear fusion and neutron absorption will lead to the formation of heavier elements, provided there is sufficient density and temperature. Intuitively, it seems that the number of D nuclei needed will be several times greater than the number of nuclei being transformed. As a result, the energy release will be comparable to the cold method. Here, the problem of capturing the products of the thermonuclear explosion arises. It may require a huge chamber with a constant magnetic field, weak enough not to affect the explosion phase but strong enough to cause the plasma to cool to an acceptable temperature as it spreads to the size of the chamber. Such an installation will not allow determining the amount of necessary isotopes but will produce many different ones, albeit in predictable proportions.
Irradiation in the particle-accelerator is probably even more energy-resource-intensive. It does not make sense to consider it.
Can there be a less energy-resource-intensive method of producing heavier elements from lighter ones? Installations much smaller than the size of a planet are considered, but not necessarily on its surface.
The question does not have a strict boundary between light and heavy elements. At a minimum, elements H, C, N, O are always assumed to be available. The task of obtaining $^4$He from $^1$H is definitely not the goal. There is more interest in obtaining odd elements, primarily Sc from Ca and those heavier than Zn from Fe or Zn.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community Nuclear transformations from light elements to heavy ones require resources and energy. The question is how to do this with minimal energy and resource expenditure. Two methods are briefly proposed. Artificial stars or their management are not being considered.
Is it possible that parts of the proposed suggestions contain spelling errors that distort their intended meaning?

Hydrogen (atomic weight about 1) to helium (atomic weight about 4) is known to be possible with net release of energy; this is how the Sun works. This means that it depends on which specific lighter species you want to convert into what specific heavier species, and on the specific chain of nuclear reactions. (Note that nuclear reactions happen with different probabilities, so you need to consider all the nuclear reactions which may happen in your specific setup.)

@AlexP I tried to clarify this partially. There may be general answers that do not depend on the boundary. I tried to briefly describe two such answers. There might be answers lying in the narrow area of mass.   The capture of slow neutrons occurs with a fairly high probability for almost all elements, which is why it is chosen in the first method. And in the second method, indeed, there will be many different reactions and a variety of products, with an abundance of even elements, which makes the second method worse than the first.

Make a large star from a ball of gas. Wait…

There is quite an effective method of doing this, and the patent has expired.

GENERAL PRINCIPLE The general principle of the present invention is to employ an atomic explosion, preferably one which derives a considerable portion of its energy from a thermonuclear fuel, to provide neutrons which may be used to produce isotopes by transmutation although any isotope which may be produced by neutron bombardment may be produced by the method of the present invention. The preferred embodiment is the production of the isotopes U, Pu, H, or Co. [Therefore, in the preferred embodiment, a suitable blanket for absorbing neutrons in thorium, uranium, lithium or cobalt, is placed on the ground, either as a large circular disk or as a lining of a partial spherical cavity on the ground. A thermonuclear bomb with a yield of the order of a mega-ton is then fired at such a distance above the ground that no appreciable cratering results and that only a very small thickness of blanket protecting material is vaporized. If desired the explosion is repeated until the desirable neutron capture product in the blanket has built to such a concentration as wanted.

The method has never been used commercially, because it involves setting off hydrogen bombs. They are quite a cheap and controllable way of producing large quantities of neutrons, and readily built. Theodore "Ted" Taylor, one of the most creative nuclear weapons designers in history, invented and patented the idea. It's one of those things we could do, but everyone is scared of.

It is the second "hot" method that is in the question. Like the first "cold" method, this is accompanied by large energy emissions, more than $10^{15}$ J/kg.

@Imyaf: Yes, but they're cheap and easy to produce this way.
